# How to solve no unicode mapping error from PDFBox?

Tags: java, python, unicode, pdfbox

I have an existing PDF file that I would like to convert to excel file using python script. Currently using PDFBox, however there are multiple errors similar to the following:

```
org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font toUnicode
No Unicode mapping for CID+24 (24) in font DroidSansFallback
```

Can I substitute the droidsansfallback font or replace the font with another font using pdfbox or other java/python script? 
Please help.

Comment: It is extremely difficult to solve these, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39485920/how-to-add-unicode-in-truetype0font-on-pdfbox-2-0-0 . The best is to contact the creator of the document to bring up a document that permits proper text extraction.

Comment: Thank you @TilmanHausherr :) would it be possible to use OCR?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr, sorry as I am new to this. Is it because the creator of the document missed out the toUnicode cmap hence of this error?

Comment: Sure you can OCR it. Try Tesseract. Apache Tika supports this. Yes the creator is at fault. It may even have been intended.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr, thank you for your help :) Will try OCR if it works. Btw other than python/java, any idea of other programming language that is able to automate the conversion of pdf to excel?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I would have to google too :-)

Comment: Okie, no worries :) Thank you @TilmanHausherr

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar lately when parsing text from PDFs

> WARNING: No Unicode mapping for 112 (142) in font AEDNQJ+Palatino-BoldItalic+2

This was causing the output result to be missing certain characters (such as á) in the output

> M_s alta que los cielos, m_s honda que la mar,

(Added underscores where the character <á> should have been in the text)

The fix is to regenerate your PDF with all fonts embedded (such as [PDF/A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/A)), so that all fonts are available at text extraction time.

Example:

```
public String parsePdf(InputStream pdfStream) {

    try (PDDocument pdfDoc = PDDocument.load(pdfStream)) {
        
        PDFTextStripper textStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        return textStripper.getText(pdfDoc);

    } catch(IOException e) {
        throw new ParsingException("Unable to load input pdf stream", e);
    }
}
```

> Más alta que los cielos, más honda que la mar,

You can convert an existing PDF to PDF/A using acrobat or the preview tool in macos.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue you're encountering is related to the lack of Unicode mapping for a specific Character ID (CID) in the font used in your PDF file. One approach to handle this is to substitute the font or replace it with another font. Unfortunately, directly replacing fonts in a PDF can be a bit complex, and there might not be a straightforward solution in PDFBox or any other tool.

Instead, a common approach is to extract the text content from the PDF and then convert it to Excel. Python provides several libraries that can assist you in achieving this, such as PyPDF2, PyMuPDF (MuPDF), or pdfplumber for extracting text from PDFs, and pandas for working with Excel files.

Here's a basic example using PyPDF2 and pandas:

```
import PyPDF2
import pandas as pd

def extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_path):
    with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as file:
        pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file)
        text_content = []
        for page_num in range(pdf_reader.numPages):
            page = pdf_reader.getPage(page_num)
            text_content.append(page.extractText())
    return text_content

def save_to_excel(text_content, excel_path):
    df = pd.DataFrame(text_content, columns=['Page Content'])
    df.to_excel(excel_path, index=False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pdf_path = 'your_existing.pdf'
    excel_path = 'output_excel_file.xlsx'

    text_content = extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_path)
    save_to_excel(text_content, excel_path)
```

This script extracts text from each page of the PDF and saves it to an Excel file. Keep in mind that the formatting might not be perfect, and you may need to clean up the data in the resulting Excel file manually.

If you have a more complex PDF with tables or specific formatting, you might need a more sophisticated approach, such as using tools like Tabula or Camelot for table extraction.

Answer (score -1):

Convert PDF using print to Microsoft pdf file and use that. It will take care of all fonts

Comment: This method will prevent any non-OCR text extraction because the "printed" pdf file is essentially an image.