# Unable to paste text in readable format from a PDF

Tags: string, pdf, unicode, character

I have a PDF document with the following sample text (screenshot) -

[image: Screenshot of the sample text from the PDF document]

But when I copy and paste it to either word or other text editors all I see is the weird characters :







I am not quite sure why does it giving me weird square boxes instead of pasting the clear human-readable letters (just like the screenshot). Can someone help me how can I get rid of this issue ? Or at least what shall I do to identify the root cause of this strange issue ?

Comment: Apparently your pdf misses the entries required for text extraction. Displaying glyphs is possible without any hint concerning a unicode code point representing that glyph as a character.

Comment: @mkl - If I understood correctly, so this can't be fixed any more ?

Comment: Depending on the number of distinct font objects in the pdf, you may attempt to inject information in that regard, compare [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39644941/1729265). And another option is OCR...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @mkl. I went with the OCR approach and it resolved by issue.

Answer (score 1):

================== Workaround found ==================

- I tried converting the document's corrupted unicode to a standard ANSCI unicode formats. But most of the online services couldn't recognize these garbage/weird characters.
- This issue could be resolved by some programming, but I don't want to invest time with the programming approach and preferred on the fly approach.
- Finally, as suggested by the user '[mkl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1729265/mkl)', converting this document by using the OCR services like "Sedja"/ "Adobe OCR" resolved by issue.