# Detect missing / corrupt Unicode mapping in PDF

Tags: java, pdf, unicode, fonts, pdfbox

While extracting text from some PDFs PDFBox returns gibberish.
This is because of a missing or corrupt Unicode mapping.
I can see following warnings on the console. 
I want to be able to detect this to be able to flag these PDFs as corrupt.

I'm looking for a solution that is better than parsing logs.

Thanks for your help!

Sample Console Logs:

```
WARNING: No Unicode mapping for CID+32 (32) in font F6
WARNING: Failed to find a character mapping for 32 in TimesNewRoman,Bold
```

Below mentioned post also talks about the same issue but doesn't talk about ways to be able to detect this on code side and handle the same: [Issue with reading some unicode characters out of a PDF using PDFBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39324398/issue-with-reading-some-unicode-characters-out-of-a-pdf-using-pdfbox)

Comment: There are a couple different ways to use PDFBox, could you share exactly how you're running it? See [mcve] for help including a good amount of code so that people wanting to answer your question can recreate your issue and better help you.

Comment: As @DavyM mentions, please provide some code to show how you use PDFBox and whenever possible, which part of the code fails

Comment: try (final PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(sourceFile))){

            PDFTextStripper str = new PDFTextStripper();
            str.getText(document);//This line throws the warnings
   
 ....
 }
 catch (IOException e) {
         System.out.println(e);
 }

Comment: Below mentioned post also talks about the same issue but doesn't talk about ways to be able to detect this on code side and handle the same. 
                                          
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39324398/issue-with-reading-some-unicode-characters-out-of-a-pdf-using-pdfbox

Comment: @Magpies3 Information that improves your question, like that code, as well as that arditional research should be edited into your question, not placed as comments. That way, all the information to answer your question is located in the question itself.

Comment: I have updated the description with the details shared above. Thanks

Comment: You didn't link to the PDF. I think a solution would be to use the `PrintTextLocations.java` example from the source code download and check whether `text.getUnicode()` is null or empty.

Comment: Because of the reason stated here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37862159/pdf-reading-via-pdfbox-in-java) processTextPosition is not called for text with missing unicode.

I dont have permissions to share the file I am working with. Please have a look at the file from above mentioned URL, this also exhibit the same issue.

[Sample File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Ke2amBgdpedUNwVTR3RVlRTFE/view)

Comment: Sorry. Try overriding `showGlyph()`.

Comment: Thanks Tilman this did the trick, i was able to override this method and get font and code information for which unicodes were missing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A fourth possibility (next to the three given in Aaron Digulla answer) is to override `showGlyph()` when extending the `PDFTextStripper` class:

```
protected void showGlyph(Matrix textRenderingMatrix, PDFont font, int code, String unicode, Vector displacement) throws IOException
{
    super.showGlyph(textRenderingMatrix, font, code, unicode, displacement);
    if (unicode == null || unicode.isEmpty())
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I see these solutions, both are a bit messy.

Solution #1: Install your own filter to the logger. The filter can check for the log message and set a thread local flag. Check the flag after calling `getText()`. Don't forget to remove the flag or your thread local map will fill up.

You can replace commons logging with something else, like logback, that supports [MDC](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html). You could then put the flag in the MDC.

Solution #2: Patch the sources of PDFbox. In the classes `PDSimpleFont` and `PDType0Font` add a getter:

```
public boolean hadEncodingProblems() {
    return !noUnicode.isEmpty();
}
```

There should be a way to get all fonts after calling `getText()`.

Solution #3: Use reflection to read the field value (kudos to [mkl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1729265/mkl)). Note that this can break with new Java versions or when a SecurityManager is installer or the default one is activated.

Comment: Yeah, I was also thinking on similar lines but wanted to check if somebody had a suggestion for a cleaner solution. Thanks for your inputs will wait to see if any one else has a suggestion before I mark this closed.

Comment: An alternative might be to apply reflection to access those `noUnicode` variables.